CriteriaQuery with max
I have a table like this :
bookName            updateId
----------------------------
LordOfTheRings      12
WheelOfTime         3
Cradle              9
WheelOfTime         14
Cradle              10
Cradle              11

How can i build a CriteriaQuery to get the maximum updateId for a given book ?
I need something like this :
bookCriteriaQuery.select(bookRoot);
bookCriteriaQuery.and(
    bookCriteriaBuilder.equal(bookRoot.get("bookName"), "Cradle"),
    bookCriteriaBuilder.max(bookRoot.get("updateId")) // <---  except this doesn't work
);
Book newest = entityManager.createQuery(bookCriteriaQuery).getSingleResult();


Your query can be slightly modified to perform the desired result like so :
    Predicate pred = cb.equal(cb.equal(bookRoot.get("bookName"), "Cradle"));
    Order order = cb.desc(bookRoot.get("updateId"));
    query.select(bookRoot).where(pred).orderBy(order);
    entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(1)
        .getResultList().stream()
        .findFirst();

Note that if your query finds more than 1 result an exception will be thrown by.getSingleResult()
